# IIS php.ini display_errors = stderr to a file?

Tags: php, iis

I am running a php app on microsoft IIS . I am debugging a problem and wants to use the php.ini   directive  display_errors = stderr . I want to see the errors messages in a file .
Is it possible in php.ini to redirect the stderr (or stdout) to a file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the errors logged into the file of your choice by appropriately setting the value of [`error_log`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log).